# What is the best way to handle several combinations to output a result?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, logic

Let's suppose I have an application with 4 different dropdowns

```html
<select name="colors" id="colors">
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
</select>

<select name="numbers" id="numbers">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select name="names" id="names">
  <option value="axel">axel</option>
  <option value="maria">maria</option>
  <option value="john">john</option>
  <option value="richard">richard</option>
</select>

<select name="status" id="status">
  <option value="eligible">eligible</option>
  <option value="not_eligible">not eligible</option>
</select>

<button>send</button>

<div>fortune: ??</div>
```

And whenever I hit send, I'm sending to the backend all the selected information. Every possible combination has a logic to retrieve a "fortune". For example, if I select the combination red-1-axel-eligible, I need to perform some sort of logic, that may or may not be the same as another possible combination.

It's there some design pattern or at least a clean way to handle this scenario, and don't end up with an unscalable solution?

Comment: Is the some kind of patter which combinations are treated the same?

Comment: they are pretty much all unique, but they can yield the same fortune

Comment: It really depends on the data. Is there any relation between the end result of a `red-1` and a `red-2`? If so, you can create a tree and build the solution as you go down and choose the path that matches with the selection. If not, you could just build a dictionary of size 3*4*4*2. There need to be more information for specific solutions.

Comment: It might be some relationship between `red-1` and `red-2` but not with all `red-{number}`. I'm searching for something to avoid creating all the possible combinations, or at least if I do, don't really do it that cumbersome